# yes/ No :Is $A \cong B ?$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ given by $A = (0, 1) \cup (3, 4)$ and $B = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)$. Is $A \cong B ?$

My attempt : yes because  both $A$ and $B$ are disconnected set and open interval

Is its true ??

Note :$\cong$ mean homeomorphism

Comment: Are you talking about topological spaces?  Does $\cong$ mean homeomorphic?

Comment: So you are saying $(0,1)\cup(2,3)\cup(4,5)$ is also homeomorphic to $A$ and $B$?

Comment: ya  im talking about homeomorphism @J.W.Tanner

Comment: yes  due to open interval @user10354138

Comment: They are homeomorphic, but that's not because both of them are disconnected and open interval. Having the same topological properties is a necessary but not sufficient condition for homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, but you should give a more rigorous argument.

Hint: can you think of an explicit homeomorphism between the two sets? You mention they're both a disjoint union of open intervals. Great! Can you pair up the left and right intervals by explicit functions? Good luck!

---

I hope this helps ^_^